# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Отказано в доступе)

Tags: java, glassfish

Такая проблема. Пытаюсь получить список файлов с FTP и в этот момент сервер зависает. Стал рыть ничего непонятно. Создается коннекшен нормально, все круто, но зависает(`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`). Дальше стал смотреть логи, и увидел такое. Эти ошибки вылезают при самом старте сервера, точнее, при деплое. я не знаю связанно это с зависанием или не нет, но хочу знать, что это. вот стектрейс

```
[2015-11-04T18:20:36.297+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1446639636297] [levelValue: 900] [[
  PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/ejb/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\ejb\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (Отказано в доступе)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:445)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:697)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6031)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5929)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
[2015-11-04T18:20:36.310+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1446639636310] [levelValue: 900] [[
  PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/C:/app/svnApp/branches/QCforCCMaven/ear/target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\app\svnApp\branches\QCforCCMaven\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:445)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:697)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6031)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5929)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте права на файл, который указан в сообщении об ошибке.
У пользователя, от имени которого вы запускаете сервер должны быть права на чтение (как минимум).

Comment: запускаю под админом идею

Comment: А файл есть там, где его ищут?)

Comment: Стоп! Он писать не может. Попробуйте очистить target. При закрытой идее.

Comment: очистил. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не работаете от имени администратора, сперва вы должны получить доступ, так как windows не дает полный доступ простым пользователям, из-за этого компилятор выдает такую ошибку

Comment: в соседнем ответе про это уже написано.